# Execute two queries at the same time

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on a small PHP script and i want to use two mysqli queries at one statement.
Here is the two queries:

```
$sql = ("select * from titles where id=$id")
$sql2 =("select * from titles where id=$id2")
```

and i want to output them in this way:

```
<li><span>RECORD FROM QUERY1</span><span>RECORD FROM QUERY2</span></li>
```

Is it possible to do this using Mysqli and PHP ?

Comment: Why not pull all the data in with the first query then process it with PHP? In my experience, no you can't execute 2 queries at once.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam this is not what im looking for ! if i use your code and when i will execute the code it will output:<li><span>RECORD1</span></li><li><span>RECORD2</span></li> i need to use data from the two queries at the same time.

Comment: @chris85 What do you exactly mean please !

Comment: It's too complicated to use both of them. You should change it into one line of script. otherwise, confirm one line and do the next.

Comment: Edit your question if you want to explain what you were actually trying to do. Nobody knows what you're trying to combine or execute at the same time. Adding some concrete code and examples often helps.

Comment: I mean pull in all the data (see @ShaifulIslam), fetch it, and output it. I don't know what you mean by "i need to use data from the two queries at the same time". If you mean you dont want to output the data until both values have been parsed than just want until you have both values... maybe post all your code so we know exactly what you're doing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Mullti Query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

> Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a
>   semicolon.

But in your example you can combine that with `OR`.

```
$sql = "select * from titles where id=$id OR id=$id2"
```

Comment: This is not what im looking for. In my table i have 2 records with different id. When i will use while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {} I won't be able to get the content of the 2 records at same time

Comment: @HafidaArhzaouy you can do it with `"select * from titles where id=$id OR id=$id2"` it give 2 id and return 2 row.

Comment: You can't echo the two rows at the same time PHP will output the 1st record then he will output the 2nd one!

Comment: you can fetch one row in one variable, and second row in another variable, then you can print two row at same time.

Comment: Also you can use `UNION` but it's crazy way.

Comment: Your code will work only if i succed to sotre the result in an array and then i can output them like <span>$row[0] / $row[1]</span>

Comment: How can i print the two rows at the same time ?

Comment: @HafidaArhzaouy You are asking for something non-standard. I'm sure, your application has a bad design. You should try another way.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. You must run two separate queries. If this is the performance that worries you, don't worry, the second query will be much faster than the former.

Look here => [mysqli.multi-query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

simplify your query to SELECT * FROM titles where id=$id && id=$id2

if ever that this is not the output you want kindly make your question clearer for everybody to understand in that way we would be able to provide you with the best answer.